# How to hide markdown punctuation from the output of PrismJS's markdown parser?

Tags: markdown, prismjs

I am trying to implement PrismJS on my blog to syntax highlight code and it works like a charm. PrismJS also has the ability to parse markdown. However, the output of parsed Markdown is showing the punctuations (such as ##, *), which I don't want.

For example, the following code

```
*Italic*
**Bold on
multiple lines**
```

looks like this in the output
**Italic**
****Bold on

multiple lines****

instead of looking like this
*Italic*
**Bold on

multiple lines**

Is this how it's supposed to be? The examples page on [prismjs.com](https://prismjs.com/examples.html) (you'll have to select Markdown from the 'Per language examples' section to see examples using Markdown) confirms the behavior that I am seeing (see attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMfdR.png)).

Is there a way I can get it to parse the markdown without showing the punctuations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <s>PrismJS also has the ability to parse markdown</s>

[PrismJS](https://prismjs.com/) is a **syntax highlighter** library. In simple words, it takes your code and makes it look like the code you see in a code editor, for example.

So, if your code block in your HTML looks like this for example: `<pre><code class="language-markdown">**Bold**</code></pre>`, it will output exactly the text content within the `code` element, as you have already noticed (with the `pre` and `code` elements around and some classes, attributes and additional `span` elements for styling purposes).
In summary, the purpose is to output the code you've written in your file in a styled way.

A **markdown parser** is what I think you are looking for. It can convert ("parse") your markdown markup to e.g. HTML markup. Taking the example from above, `**Bold**` is parsed to `<strong>Bold</strong>`.
If you search for "Markdown editor", you will find dozens of tools that basically do the same thing:
`markdown code (input) ---parse---> html code (output)`.

There are also many markdown parsers out there. I found this [article on CSS Tricks about how to choose the right Markdown parser](https://css-tricks.com/choosing-right-markdown-parser/). The article is from 2016, but it's still helpful and gives a good overview.
There are some parser that are extendable and can be used along with syntax highlighting (libraries).

The implementation varies depending on the chosen parser, the exact target, the tech stack used, and how the parsing should actually be implemented (e.g. backend or frontend). The most common parsers are well documented and provide straightforward information about what is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That's what I ended up doing - use a separate markdown parser for parsing, you know, markdown :D